# Multiple contact form on the same page jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form with TMForm.js and MailHandler.php that works well.

Now I want to add an other contact form on the same html page and I want to identify the second form in the e-mail that I will receive from the submission.

The problem is that works only the first form. How can i resolve the problem?

This is my code:
HTML:

```
         <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="bat/MailHandler.php">
                  <div class="success_wrapper">
                    <div class="success-message">Il messaggio è stato inviato
                      con successo. Sarai contattato al più presto.</div>
                  </div>
                  <label class="name"> <input placeholder="Nome*:" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"

                      type="text"> <span class="empty-message">*Questo campo è
                      obbligatorio.</span> <span class="error-message">*Nome
                      non valido. Inserisci un nome valido.</span> </label> 
                      <label class="email"> <input placeholder="E-mail*:" data-constraints="@Required @Email"

                      type="text"> <span class="empty-message">*Questo campo è
                      obbligatorio.</span> <span class="error-message">*E-mail
                      non valido. Inserisci un e-mail valido.</span> </label> <label

                    class="phone"> <input placeholder="Telefono:" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"

                      type="text"> <span class="empty-message">*Questo campo è
                      obbligatorio.</span> <span class="error-message">*Numero
                      di telefono non valido. Inserisci un numero valido</span>
                  </label> <label class="message"> <textarea placeholder="Messaggio*:"

                      data-constraints="@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)" style="height: 72px"></textarea>
                    <span class="empty-message">*Questo campo è obbligatorio.</span>
                    <span class="error-message">*Il messaggio è troppo corto.</span>
                  </label>
                  <div>
                    <div class="btn"> <a class="def-btn btn1" href="#" data-type="submit">INVIA
                        RICHIESTA</a>
                      <p class="fields">*Campi
 obbligatori</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

This is the TMform.js:

```
//TMForm
(function($){
        $.fn.TMForm=function(opt){
                return this.each(TMForm)

                function TMForm(){
                        var form=$(this)
                        opt=$.extend({                                  
                                        okClass:'ok'
                                        ,emptyClass:'empty'
                                        ,invalidClass:'invalid'
                                        ,successClass:'success'
                                        ,onceVerifiedClass:'once-verified'
                                        ,mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php'                                   
                                        ,successShowDelay:'20000'
                                        ,stripHTML:true
                                },opt)

                        init()

                        function init(){                                
                                form
                                        .on('submit',formSubmit)
                                        .on('reset',formReset)
                                        .on('focus','[data-constraints]',function(){
                                                $(this).parents('label').removeClass(opt.emptyClass)
                                        })
                                        .on('blur','[data-constraints]:not(.once-verified)',function(){
                                                $(this)
                                                        .addClass(opt.onceVerifiedClass)
                                                        .trigger('validate.form')
                                        })
                                        .on('keyup','[data-constraints].once-verified',function(){                                              
                                                $(this).trigger('validate.form')
                                        })                                      

                                if($('[data-constraints]',form).length!==0)
                                        $('[data-constraints]',form)
                                                .regula('bind')
                                                .on('show.placeholder',function(){
                                                        fieldDesolation($(this))
                                                })
                                                .on('validate.form',fieldValidate)


                                $('[placeholder]',form).TMPlaceholder()

                                $('[data-type=submit]',form)
                                        .click(function(){                                              
                                                form.trigger('submit')
                                                return false
                                        })

                                $('[data-type=reset]',form)
                                        .click(function(){                                              
                                                form.trigger('reset')
                                                return false
                                        })
                        }

                        function fieldValidate(el){
                                var el=$(this)
                                        ,result=el.regula('validate')
                                        ,isEmpty=false
                                        ,isInvalid=false
                                        ,isRequired=!!~el.data('constraints').indexOf('@Required')

                                $.each(result,function(){
                                        if(this.constraintName==='Required')
                                                isEmpty=true
                                        else
                                                isInvalid=true
                                })

                                if(!el.hasClass(opt.onceVerifiedClass)&&!isEmpty)
                                        el.addClass(opt.onceVerifiedClass)

                                if(isEmpty)
                                        el.parents('label').addClass(opt.emptyClass)

                                if(isInvalid&&!isEmpty&&isRequired)
                                        el.parents('label')
                                                .removeClass(opt.emptyClass)
                                                .removeClass(opt.okClass)
                                                .addClass(opt.invalidClass)

                                if(isInvalid&&!isRequired&&el.val())
                                        el.parents('label')
                                        .removeClass(opt.emptyClass)
                                        .removeClass(opt.okClass)
                                        .addClass(opt.invalidClass)

                                if(!result.length)
                                        el.parents('label')
                                                .removeClass(opt.invalidClass)
                                                .removeClass(opt.emptyClass)
                                                .addClass(opt.okClass)
                        }

                        function fieldDesolation(el){
                                el
                                        .removeClass(opt.onceVerifiedClass)
                                        .parents('label')
                                                .removeClass(opt.invalidClass)
                                                .removeClass(opt.emptyClass)
                                                .removeClass(opt.okClass)
                        }

                        function getValue(el){
                                return el.val()||false
                        }

                        function formSubmit(){
                                $('[data-constraints]',form).trigger('validate.form')

                                if(!$('label.'+opt.invalidClass+',label.'+opt.emptyClass,form).length){                                 
                                        $.ajax({
                                                type:"POST"
                                                ,url:opt.mailHandlerURL
                                                ,data:{
                                                        name:getValue($('label.name input'))
                                                        ,email:getValue($('label.email input'))
                                                        ,phone:getValue($('label.phone input'))
                                                        ,fax:getValue($('label.fax input'))
                                                        ,state:getValue($('label.state input'))
                                                        ,message:getValue($('label.message textarea'))
                                                        ,owner_email:opt.ownerEmail||'myemail@gmail.com'
                                                        ,stripHTML:opt.stripHTML
                                                }
                                                ,success: function(e){                                                  
                                                        form.addClass(opt.successClass)
                                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                                                form
                                                                .removeClass(opt.successClass)
                                                                .trigger('reset')
                                                        },opt.successShowDelay)
                                                }
                                        })                                      
                                }                               
                                return false
                        }

                        function formReset(){
                                fieldDesolation($('[data-constraints]',form))                                   
                        }
                }
        }       
})(jQuery)

;(function($){
        $.fn.TMPlaceholder=function(opt){
                return this.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                                ,placeholder_text
                                ,placeholder

                        opt=$.extend({
                                        placeholderClass:'_placeholder'
                                        ,placeholderFocusedClass:'focused'
                                        ,placeholderHiddenClass:'hidden'
                                },opt)

                        init()

                        function init(){
                                placeholder_text=th.attr('placeholder')
                                placeholder=$(document.createElement('span'))
                                placeholder
                                        .addClass(opt.placeholderClass)
                                        .css({                          
                                                left:th.prop('offsetLeft')
                                                ,top:th.prop('offsetTop')
                                                ,width:th.width()
                                                ,height:th.outerHeight()                                
                                        })
                                        .text(placeholder_text)
                                        .appendTo(th.parent())                          
                                        .click(function(){
                                                th.focus()
                                                return false
                                        })
                                        .on('contextmenu',function(){                                           
                                                th.trigger('hide.placeholder').focus()                                          
                                        })

                                th
                                        .val('')
                                        .removeAttr('placeholder')
                                        .on('hide.placeholder',function(){
                                                placeholder.addClass(opt.placeholderHiddenClass)
                                        })
                                        .on('show.placeholder',function(){
                                                placeholder.removeClass(opt.placeholderHiddenClass)
                                        })
                                        .on('focus',function(){
                                                placeholder.addClass(opt.placeholderFocusedClass)
                                        })
                                        .on('blur',function(){
                                                var val=th.val()
                                                if(val===''||val===placeholder_text)
                                                        th.val('')                                                      
                                                        ,th.trigger('show.placeholder')
                                                placeholder.removeClass(opt.placeholderFocusedClass)
                                        })
                                        .on('keydown',function(e){                                                                                              
                                                if(e.keyCode===32||e.keyCode>46)
                                                        th.trigger('hide.placeholder')                                                  
                                        })
                                        .on('keyup',function(){                                         
                                                if(th.val()===''){                                                      
                                                        th.trigger('show.placeholder')
                                                        return false
                                                }else{                                                  
                                                        th.trigger('hide.placeholder')
                                                }
                                        })
                                        .parents('form').on('reset',function(){
                                                th.trigger('show.placeholder')                                          
                                        })
                        }                       
                })
        }
})(jQuery)
//using suggested jQuery practice by passing jQuery into a function
//in order to have $ notation without conflicting with other libraries
//Author: Troy Ingram



//HERE WAS SOME VALIDATION CODE THAT I CANCELLED IN THIS PAGE

regula.custom({
        name:'JustLetters'
        ,validator:function(){
                return /^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/.test(this.value)
        }
})
regula.custom({
        name:'JustNumbers'
        ,validator:function(){
                return /^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/.test(this.value)
        }
})
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#contact-form').TMForm({
           ownerEmail:'myemail@gmail.com' 
        })



    })
```

And this is the PHP:

```
<?php
        $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
        $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $subject = 'NEW MESSAGE ' . $_POST["name"];
        $messageBody = "";

        if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
                $messageBody .= '<p>Nome: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
                $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
        }
        if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
                $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
                $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
        }else{
                $headers = '';
        }
        if($_POST['state']!='nope'){            
                $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
                $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
        }
        if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){            
                $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
                $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
        }       
        if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){              
                $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
                $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
        }
        if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
                $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        }

        if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
                $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
        }

        try{
                if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
                        throw new Exception('mail failed');
                }else{
                        echo 'mail sent';
                }
        }catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
?>
```

Comment: first guess is you gave both forms the same ID.

Comment: Hi, if i use two different IDs, the first contact form don't work.

Comment: did you initialize using both selectors? ID's must be unique by defintiion

Comment: What are you referring to with "initialize using both selectors"? How to do it?

Comment: `$('#formID#1, #formID#2').TMForm(....`

Comment: I'm not expert in this, can you be more explicit? Where i have to put the initialization?

Answer (score 1):

For SUBMIT Btn of form no.1 -> use

```
name="formFirst"
```

And for SUBMIT Btn of form no.2 -> use

```
name="formSecond"
```

And in PHP code check

```
if(isset($_POST['formFirst'])){
//Your code for  1st Form submit.
}
else if (isset($_POST['formSecond'])){
//Your code for 2nd
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I tried your solution but in this way no one form work. What can be?

Comment: The jquery is not activated because when i click on submit go to #

Comment: @user3353259 , then activate jQuery . Can't you do some coding by yourself instead of me doing all spoonfeeding ?

Answer (score 0):

With TMForm, you need to give each form a unique ID (by changing the `<form id="form">` line in your HTML to say `<form id="form1">` for the first form, and `<form id="form2">` for your second form. Then, you need to tell TMForm to look for both of those ID's.

To do that, go all the way to the bottom of the TMForm.js file and replace

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#form').TMForm({
      ownerEmail:'#' 
  })
})
```

with

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#form1').TMForm({
      ownerEmail:'#' 
  })
})

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#form2').TMForm({
      ownerEmail:'#' 
  })
})
```

You didn't post any CSS, but if you're using a template similar to the one I did, you may find you now have issues with things displaying incorrectly on the page. That is because form.css uses #form for almost everything, and you just changed that ID to two different things.

Easiest solution I found was to Find-&-Replace all instances of #form in the css file with .tmform

Then, in your HTML, make your ID's look like this:

```
<form id="form" class="tmform">
```